# PHP Zend Framework validators (String) (Error messages on my language)

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework, model

I have the next code in a model:

```
public function getInputFilter()
    {
        if (!$this->inputFilter) {
            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
            $factory     = new InputFactory();

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                    'name'     => 'id',
                    'required' => true,
                    'filters'  => array(
                            array('name' => 'Int'),
                    ),
            )));


            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                    'name'     => 'query',
                    'required' => true,
                    'filters'  => array(
                            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                    ),
                    'validators' => array(
                            array(
                                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                                    'options' => array(
                                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                                            'min'      => 1,
                                            'max'      => 256,
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
            )));

            $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
        }

        return $this->inputFilter;
    }
```

What I have to add, to the code become with error messages in my language ( non english)? (Errors : **"required"**, "StringLength")

Comment: Are you asking how to get the validation error message in another language?

Comment: Zend has predefined translations for the validations of multiple languages. If yours is also in the resources, you can use the Zend Translator and set it with the method setDefaultTranslator method in AbstractValidator. I'm not sure, but I guess it also can be set in the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will have seen an information about the validator:
[Zend 2.1 Validator](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.validator.html)